# How to create a private endpoint in flask

Tags: python, flask, web

In my flask application I need to fetch data from my database whenever the users clicks a button, I know I can just make a flask route, using the flask restful module or plain routes. But my question is if I can make that route/endpoint not visible for users.

```java
@app.route("/api/fetch/")
def fetch_data():
    return some_data
```

I dont wan't the user having access to this endpoint directly, I just want the web application to be able to use it. Not sure if it is possible or where to look.

I found that maybe using **Flask-CORS** could help. Any help or guidance would be appreciated.

Comment: add an **api key** for that endpoint.

Comment: You can use Token authorization for the routes that you want. Only users that have the authorization for that route can use it. There are a lot of tutorials about this topic.

Comment: The safest thing would be to have /api/fetch look at the address of the machine making the request, and verify that its on the same subnet as the server.

Comment: @FrankYellin I will it a shot, this way my web app can use the endpoint and the user has no access outside of my application right?

Comment: @StephanGuingor No, their suggestion is terrible.  Use an api key if you need your app to have route access, but not your user.

Comment: If the request is coming from outside your own network, just set back a 404 error.  If the request is coming from inside your network, respond appropriately.   The outside user doesn't need to know that the endpoint even exists.

Comment: Ip address whitelisting is also an option you can consider -  accept requests from known IP addresses

Comment: @MaximilianBurszley.  You claim my idea is bad, but without giving any reason.  In the best of all possible worlds, they'd use both an API key and only answer good addresses.  But why do you think one is better than the other?  An API key can be leaked.  It's harder to spoof an IP address when you're also expecting a response to be sent to that address.

Comment: @MaximilianBurszley Why is terrible? And why is using an api key is the better option?

Comment: The problem with tokens is they have to be distributed.  Does your source code live in Git?  Will someone looking at your github repository see the token?  I prefer a solution that doesn't involve secrets.  I'm granting you access if you're on a machine I trust.

Answer (score 0):

On flask you can use Blueprint
example from the above snippet would be

```
from flask import Blueprint

sample_bp = Blueprint("sample_bp", __name__)

@sample_bp.before_request
def restrict_with_token():
    # Do something here on checking header or token

@sample_bp.route("/api/fetch/")
def fetch_api():
    # Your logic
```

Otherwise you can have some referrence here : https://flask.palletsprojects.com/en/1.1.x/tutorial/views/